# There is no active transaction when multiple AJAX requests from same user

Tags: ajax, laravel, pdo, cockroachdb

I have a rather embarrassing problem.

In a conversation system, when the user sends a message, an AJAX request is sent and then a PDO transaction is created to make multiple INSERT and UPDATE.

To test, I spammed the sending of messages, resulting in multiple AJAX requests being sent in parallel. Out of ten messages sent "at the same time", several transactions will bug, the Laravel error handler sends me "There is no active transaction".

Is it a PDO configuration problem? I put DB::beginTransaction above a try catch. Apparently, the bug is in the DB::commit, which detects when there is no more transaction in progress.
Is it the fact that it is my "user session" that sends AJAX requests that cancels a PDO transaction on another request than the current one?

I use Laravel 5.8.19 and CockroachDB 19.1.1.1.

Thanks for the help.